# Local Nuget package not recognizing

Tags: c#, nuget-package, .net-core

I have created class library project in vs 2015 of version 4.6 and after that i have created Local Nuget package.

I have created 2nd project in .NET core in Vs 2015 and added local Nuget package of above one, but when i am trying to use it the package is not getting recognize and no intellisense also, so please help.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're saying correctly, you created a NuGet package for a .Net Framework 4.6 library and now you're trying to use it from a .Net Core application.

That won't work, .Net Core is not directly compatible with .Net Framework. What you need to do is to create a .Net Standard library. You will then be able to use that from .Net Core or from .Net Framework.